# Finding potential difference for one side of a parallel plate capacitor with dielectrics in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, capacitance, dielectric

I'm doing some homework problems and there's a question that asks for the potential difference of the left side of a parallel plate capacitor that looks like this:

```
--------------------------
         plate 1
--------------------------
            |
     ε1     |     ε2
            |
--------------------------
         plate 2
--------------------------
```

The entire capacitor is charged by a battery of emf V before being disconnected by the battery. I'm going to assume that means that that means the potential difference of the entire parallel plate capacitor is V. However, we are asked to solve the potential difference across the left side of the plates. I'm not sure how to get this calculations as I'm not sure of the relationship of potential differences for parallel plates with dielectrics in parallel.

If anybody can provide some insights into this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The potential difference is the same on both sides since the configuration is essentially two different capacitors in parallel. It is the charge that is different on each side due to the different capacitance.  Capacitance, voltage and charge are related by the equation

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

Hope this helps.